# Nested objects in GET_LIST response

Tags: spring-boot, react-admin

I am attempting to use a simpleRestProvider. My backend is spring boot. Using starter web, data-rest, etc.. Backend response for the the GET_LIST endpoint is:

```
{"content":[
   {"id":1,"title":"Title One","content":"Content One","date":[2014,12,1,1,1],"published":true},
   {"id":2,"title":"Title Two","content":"Content Two","date":[2015,2,10,1,1],"published":true}
]}
```

I cannot get past the error from react-admin:

> The response to 'GET_LIST' must be like { data : [...] }, but the
>   received data is not an array. The dataProvider is probably wrong for
>   'GET_LIST'

Looking at the debugger in react-admin i see my response has been wrapped in a data object so it looks like this:

> data: {content: Array(2)}

And is failing on line 35 of fetch.ts in ra-core.sideEffects

```
    if (
    fetchActionsWithArrayOfRecordsResponse.includes(type) &&
    !Array.isArray(response.data)
) {
    logger(
        `The response to '${type}' must be like { data : [...] }, but the received data is not an array. The dataProvider is probably wrong for '${type}'`
    );
    throw new Error('ra.notification.data_provider_error');
}
```

I understand what's happening is that response.data is not an array and I am nested one level too deep.

I am unable to either: 
A) configure react-admin to look at my response and not wrap it in a data object 
B) return a array from spring that is not encapsulated in a content object.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a dataProvider from the SimpleRestProvider and modified the return from the converHttpResponse.